# how do i create a table column that is connected to another table in sql SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, relational-database

[image]

Under the music column of playlist table, I want the it to connect to the music table.

Comment: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

i think  you should use here FOREIGN KEY

A Foreign Key allows us to associate a row in one table to a row in another table. This is done by setting a column in one table as a Foreign Key and having that column reference another table's Primary Key column

syntax :

FOREIGN KEY (fk_col_name) REFERENCES target_table_name (pk_col_name);